# Bootstrap tabs doesn't switch

Tags: html

i am trying to use bootstrap tabs using the following code

```
<div class="block full">
    <div class="block-title">
        <h2>Head</small></h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs push" data-toggle="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#example-tabs-home">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#example-tabs-profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#example-tabs-messages" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Messages"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i></a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#example-tabs-settings" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Settings"><i class="icon-cogs"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="example-tabs-home">Home..</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="example-tabs-profile">Profile..</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="example-tabs-messages">Messages..</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="example-tabs-settings">Settings..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but when i try to use it. it doesn't switch tabs but **adds** the tab content to the current one....

Note: i have jquery, bootstrap scripts referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem was you were using `data-toggle="tooltip"` and you should have been using `data-toggle="tab"`

This works.

```
<div class="block full">
    <div class="block-title">
        <h2>Head</small></h2>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs push" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#example-tabs-home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-tabs-profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-tabs-messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-original-title="Messages"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#example-tabs-settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-original-title="Settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="example-tabs-home">Home</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="example-tabs-profile">Profile</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="example-tabs-messages">Messages</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="example-tabs-settings">Settings</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: well it was fixed when i re downloaded bootstrap files.. probably it was a corrupted js or css bootstrap...

Comment: I used your code with the most recent version of bootstrap via CDN and it did not work, so I doubt it was corrupted bootstrap or js...